# How make conditional expression on Django with default value of object?

Tags: django, django-models

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/
conditional expression with Case;

```
o = Object.annotate(
   custom_price=Case(
                    When(price=1, then=Value(2)),
                    default=0,
                    output_field=DecimalField(),
                )
            )
```

How use set 'default' - current value of Object? 
Now it writed only as const: 0

Want something like:

```
if price =1:
    custom_price = 2
else:
    custom_price = Object.price
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`F` is used to perform this. So, your code should look like:

```
   from django.db.models import Case, F, Value, When, DecimalField
   o = Object.objects.annotate(custom_price=Case(
                When(price=1, then=Value(2)),
                default=F('price'),
                output_field=DecimalField(),
            )
        )
```